# How do you do a sweep kick in Ultimate Mortal Kombat 3 for snes

Tags: snes, mortal-kombat-3

I'm playing Ultimate Mortal Kombat 3 for snes the computer characters do sweep kicks constantly but I can't figure out how to do it. when I duck hit lowkick I just get like a little jaby kind of kick not the spinning sweep kick.

Comment: Have you tried down *and* back, then low kick?

Comment: oh, duh thats it

Comment: title says... snes, but you tagged sega-genesis?

Comment: fixed, though i expect its the same command for both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hold Away/Back/<-- and Light Kick you can do the leg sweep.